# MinLength constraint on ICollection fails, Entity Framework

Tags: casting, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-4.3, icollection

This is the datamodel I have:

```
public class Team
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set;} 
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [MinLength(1)]
    public virtual ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }
}
```

My issue is that when I later try to create a new Team (that has one user) I get the following issue when the context is saving.

> An unexpected exception was thrown during validation of 'Users' when invoking System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.MinLengthAttribute.IsValid. See the inner exception for details.

The inner exception is the following:

> {"Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[MyNameSpace.Model.User]' to type 'System.Array'."}

Here is the code for the actual saving (which for now is in the controller):

```
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            team.Users = new List<User>();
            team.Users.Add(CurrentUser);//CurrentUser is a property that gives me the currently active User (MyNamespace.Model.User).
            DB.Teams.Add(team);//DB is a DbContext object that holds DbSets of all my models
            DB.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
```

So, what's going on here? Am I doing something wrong, or is there something else happening?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I do not believe that you will be able to use the MinLength Attribute for what you are trying to achieve.  [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.minlengthattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is the msdn page for the MinLength Attribute.  Based on the description:  *"Specifies the minimum length of array of **string** data allowed in a property."*  So as you can see it can only be used against arrays of string data.  You may need to create your own custom ValidationAttribute to handle your scenario.

Comment: Your answer appears to be right, but you misquoted the MSDN page. It reads: "Specifies the minimum length of array or string data allowed in a property." (or, not of).

It's unfortunate that they chose not to make it support collections. That seems like it would have been the obvious choice, but oh well...